# Expressjs secure session cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I cant seem to find a way to set a secure cookie in expressjs framework. Is there an option to do this somewhere?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html), try this:

```
res.cookie('rememberme', 'yes', { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000), httpOnly: true, secure: true });
```

Using `res.cookie(name, val[, options])` sets the given cookie name to `val`, with options `httpOnly`, `secure`, `expires`, etc. The `path` option defaults to the app’s `basepath` setting, which is typically `"/"`.

See the [docs for `res.cookie`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie) for more details.

Comment: well i tried setting it in the session settings object as in the connect docs. Like `key: 'session_cookie', cookie: { maxAge:bl bla, secure: true }` But it doesn't work :/ I can change the name and so on, but not set it to secure. Can't find anything on this...

Comment: Yes that option works too! the only one that doesn't work is the secure option. Can't figure this one out haha

Comment: It took a couple of restarts of the server. i also cleared the cache and cookies in the browser. And then suddenly the cookie was checked as secure.

Answer (score 27):

If you are behind a proxy, you also have to ensure it is sending the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header and that you set the proxy option:

```
app.use(express.session({
  proxy: true,
  secret: 'test',
  cookie: {
    secure: true
  }            
}));
```

Alternatively, you can tell Express to trust the proxy globally:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
```

Comment: Same issue on Heroku and Modulus. The accepted answer is deprecated, this is the way to go.