# How to use CookieSession secure option?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I have installed a NPM by the name of cookie-session v2.0 which I want to use to transport a JWT to a client browser with HTTPS protocol.
However when I want to set the secure option to true according to the documentation of https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-session, I receive an error which indicates the following:

```
Argument of type '{ signed: false; secure: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ httpOnly?: boolean; keys?: any[]; name?: string; overwrite?: boolean; secret?: string; signed?: boolean; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'secure' does not exist in type '{ httpOnly?: boolean; keys?: any[]; name?: string; overwrite?: boolean; secret?: string; signed?: boolean; }'. Did you mean to write 'secret'?
```

and if I hover over cookieSession, I can see clearly that there is no such property assigned according the documentation.

```
(alias) cookieSession(options?: {
    httpOnly?: boolean;
    keys?: any[];
    name?: string;
    overwrite?: boolean;
    secret?: string;
    signed?: boolean;
}): Function
import cookieSession
```

This is my code so far in my expressApp file:

```
const express = require("express");
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const cors = require("cors");
const { errorHandler } = require("./middleware");
const { NotFoundError } = require("./errors");

const routers = require("./routes");

const expressApp = function async(app) {
  app.set("trust proxy", true);
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(
    cookieSession({
      signed: false,
    })
  );
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "1mb" }));
  app.use(cors());

  app.use("/api/v1", routers);

  app.all("*", async (req, res) => {
    throw new NotFoundError();
  });

  app.use(errorHandler);
};

module.exports = expressApp;
```

How can I fix this issue so I can set the secure option to true?

Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: You can in your cookieSession set secure:true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation you linked

> Cookie Options -
> Other options are passed to `cookies.get()` and `cookies.set()` allowing you to control security, domain, path, and signing among other settings.

You cannot set cookies to be secure while you are creating the `cookieSession` in `app.use` but you can set it when you setting or getting the cookie in your route.

`cookies.set({ secure: true });`

Check this answer out on [how to send secure cookie in expressjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8455316/7482427)